# is "C# with Selenium automation scripting" opt job for a developer?

Tags: automated-tests

Can a developer accept a offer with jd of “c # with selenium" automation scripting ?The JD sounds like it's related to tester who writes testing automation, what is the role of a developer in it? Can any one guide me in this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual for test automation jobs to ask for at least some level of developer experience.

Test automation code is kind of a software development project. You *do* code the tests, after all. Not to say that development and test automation are the same, but there is some overlap.